# How to add buttons in Table Of Content (TOC) or below TOC in Docusaurus?

Tags: javascript, docusaurus

I want to add custom buttons below auto generated Table of Content.
Ideally , I want to use the space below TOC to add my custom buttons.
Or maybe i could create a plugin that would generate TOC differently and  generete button that i have added in .md file in table of content.

This is output I want
[image]

Comment: No. I havenot found it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I can share solution that I used in the similar situation.
[Swizzling](https://docusaurus.io/docs/swizzling) concept of docusaurus will allow to put custom logic inside existing components. To put buttons above or below TOC you can swizzle `DocItem` component and add custom buttons where necessary.

So in swizzled DocItem component you should find `<TOC/>` component and put buttons below it. Also you can apply styles as well

```
...
// TOC below can look different in your version of docusaurus
<TOC
 toc={DocContent.toc}
 minHeadingLevel={tocMinHeadingLevel}
 maxHeadingLevel={tocMaxHeadingLevel}
 className={styles.yourClass}
/>
<div className={styles.yourStyles}>
  <button>Documentation</button>
  <button>Release notes</button>
</div>
...
```